# Autowiring services in Symfony 4 (Too few arguments)

Tags: php, symfony, autowired

I do have simple command with constructor requiring `LoggerInterface` as dependency.

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

// use (...)

class ProcessReportCommand extends Command
{
    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    // (...)
}
```

My configuration in `services.yml` looks pretty default:

```
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false      

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Exception,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Unfortunately I am getting PHP Error saying that dependency was not injected.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Too
>   few arguments to function
>   App\Command\ProcessReportCommand::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   /home/tomasz/project/bin/console on line 40 and exactly 1 expected in
>   /home/tomasz/project/src/Command/ProcessReportCommand.php:17

Even if I will switch this dependency to any other class which I have under `App\` it behaves always like that.
I literally have no idea what should I do more to make it works, all ways even the one with including explicitly the service inside `services.yml` does not work for me. Any clues?

Comment: Did you clear the cache? `php bin/console cache:clear`. If that does not work, what are the outputs of `php bin/console debug:container Process`?

Comment: Well, I can not even use `bin/console` because it's throwing me `Fatal Error` like above, even when I remove `var/cache/*` manually

Comment: Can I take a look to your `composer.json` to make sure that you are using the right dependencies?

Comment: Sure     `"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.7",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "netresearch/jsonmapper": "^1.4",
        "symfony/console": "^4.0",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
    },`

Comment: Great, everything looks fine. Your autowiring and autoconfiguring should work if you are requiring the right class. Are you sure the command class you are extending from is the Symfony one?

Comment: Yes, it's extending `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command` so all should be ok, I don't know what can be wrong there.

Comment: That is absolutely weird. I use Symfony 4 and I've never ran into an autowiring problem like yours. Maybe you've found some sort of bug in Symfony. Could you share your stack trace please? In the mean time, I'll try to replicate.

Comment: It looks like I had to make somewhere a mistake, I quickly setup new project only with command and it runs like it should with autowire. I will try to investigate what was leading to that problem and I will let you know if I will find anything. So far thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah, I did the same and it worked also. Let me know what you discover. You are not using compiler passes or something like that right?

Comment: No so far it's pretty simple app and I stuck because of that, anyway I'm going to investigate after I will make some steps forward :)

Comment: How are you accessing the service?

Comment: In app/AppKernel.php, do you register the "MonologBundle" in "registerBundles" function using"new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),"?

Comment: On symfony 3 I had this error and helped removing child service definition. Child service was not autowired and had 2 arguments. I was no using child service for but maybe symfony tried to still autowire it.

Comment: this occurs for argument using construct while initiating the class.

Comment: Please don't ask for clarification using an answer. Use the comment section instead